# Rails 3 fail validation for parent model is validation of nested attributes fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have two models, User and House. They have one-to-one association.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :name, :house_attributes
   has_one :house, :dependent => :destroy
   validates :name, :presence => true
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :house, allow_destroy: true, :reject_if =>    lambda { |a| a['desc'].blank? }
end

class House < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :desc, :price
   belongs_to :user
   validates :desc, :presence => true
end
```

Now I created a nested form inside of User new view like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f_builder.simple_fields_for :house, @house do |h| %>
    <%= h.input :price %>
    <%= h.input :desc %>
   <% end %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

And the new controller is like this

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  @house = @user.build_house

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
  end
end
```

I want to always create a house at the same time that user is created. So if house fails validation, it should not create user. (Now the house model has only one validation, which is :desc field needs to be present.)

The code in models, only guarantee house is not created, if :desc is blank. But it will still create the user.

I tried to add custom validation inside of User model, but can not find a way to access :desc attribute (failed to call self.desc) or :house_attributes (self.house_attributes) inside of User model. I really don't know where does rails store these house attributes before a house is created.

I hope you guys can help me figure out a nice and clear way to

1) Be able to validate and show error message for :desc attribute. Right now errors message will only show up for :name field of User model.

2) Do not save user if validation for either user or house is failed.

3) If any of validation failed, render :new

Thanks

Comment: did you find a solution? I need to validate a nested attribute date against a parent date before saving

Comment: @scanales No. I ended up not using nested_attributes

Answer (score 3):

You should add `validates_associated :house` to your User model. This will run the House validations and ensure they succeed before considering the user to be valid.

Comment: I think it will do the same thing as :reject_if inside of accepts_nested_attributes_for, that is: it will not create house, but it will still create user